# How to handle error of sendmessage() of the conversationToolkitApi?

Tags: aura, consoleintegrationtoolkit

No matter how I try to catch the error of this function - with a catch clause or try/catch block, it always gives me "Uncaught (in promise)  " message in the console and doesn't get to the error handling branches:

```
({
    sendMessage: function(cmp, evt, helper) {
        var conversationKit = cmp.find("conversationKit");
        var recordId = cmp.get("v.recordId");
        conversationKit.sendMessage({
            recordId: recordId,
            message: {
                text:"Hi, this was sent using the sendMessage API!"
            }
        })
        .then(function(result){
            if (result) {
                    console.log("Successfully sent message");
                } else {
                    //this is never reached
                    console.log("Failed to send message");
                }
        })
        .catch(function(result) {
               //this is never reached either
               console.error('handle error');
        });
    }
})
```

The stack looks like this:
[image: promise rejected]

How do you actually detect there's been an error?